# jQuery date check using .now()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, date

Thanks in advance.

I am using the below code to remove table rows from a table based on a date. The table shows upcoming bookings but I would like to include the bookings from that same day in the table and remove only past bookings. 
If the date is before today then hide the row.

Heres the HTML.This is part of a loop by the way.

```
<table style="width:100%;" class="dashboard_widget" id="bookingsdashboard">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <p><strong>Booking Ref</strong></p>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p><strong>Arrival Date</strong></p>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p><strong>Booking Type</strong></p>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <p><strong>Operator Name</strong></p>
                    </th>
                    <th class="options">
                        <p><strong>Options</strong></p>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>



                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>MR Design Et Al</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td id="arrivaldate-widget">
                        <p><span class="arrivaldate-widget-unix" style="display:none;">1434844800</span> 21.06.2015<br>(9 nights)</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Corporate</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Operatex</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/scpads/wp-admin/post.php?post=225&amp;action=edit"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-right:10px;"></i>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>   





                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>Mr Knopps</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td id="arrivaldate-widget">
                        <p><span class="arrivaldate-widget-unix" style="display:none;">1429574400</span> 21.04.2015<br>(343 nights)</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Groups</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Operatorsio</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/scpads/wp-admin/post.php?post=219&amp;action=edit"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-right:10px;"></i>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>   





                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>Mr Knopps</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td id="arrivaldate-widget">
                        <p><span class="arrivaldate-widget-unix" style="display:none;">1456012800</span> 21.02.2016<br>(297 nights)</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Groups</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Operatorsio</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/scpads/wp-admin/post.php?post=220&amp;action=edit"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-right:10px;"></i>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>   





                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>Mr Knopps</h3>
                    </td>
                    <td id="arrivaldate-widget">
                        <p><span class="arrivaldate-widget-unix" style="display:none;">1429574400</span> 21.04.2015<br>(6 nights)</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Groups</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>Operatorsio</p>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="http://www.greenmonkeypublicrelations.com/scpads/wp-admin/post.php?post=218&amp;action=edit"><i class="fa fa-file-text" style="padding-right:10px;"></i>Edit</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>   


            </tbody></table>
```

Heres the jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var date = jQuery('.arrivaldate-widget-unix').val();
  var time = jQuery.now();
  if (date < time ) {
    jQuery('.arrivaldate-widget-unix').closest('tr').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: in what format is the arrivaldate-widget-unix? I suspect that returns a text date right?

Comment: Would be helpful if you mention the value of date variable. That will give a clear picture of problem.

Comment: Dory. The .val() is a unix timestamp. 
Satpal. The problem is that the function also hides all rows where the date is the same as the current day. The purpose of the table is to show the upcoming bookings including those that fall on that day.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you need to hide rows*

You need to use [`.each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over object

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var time = jQuery.now(); //OR new Date(jQuery.now())
    jQuery('.arrivaldate-widget-unix').each(function(){
        var date = jQuery(this).val();          
        if (date < time ) {
            jQuery(this).closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT**,  To compare with only date part use

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var today = new Date();

    //Only date part
    today.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    jQuery('.arrivaldate-widget-unix').each(function(){
        var date = jQuery(this).val();          
        if (date < today ) {
            jQuery(this).closest('tr').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your assuming correctly, but the function works to hide the rows. The issue is that the function also hides all rows where the date is the same as the current day. The purpose of the table is to show the upcoming bookings including those that fall on that day.

Comment: @AlexKnopp, It would be better if you show the HTML, then surely we will have better idea and help you

Comment: @Saptal, HTML has been added above

Comment: Would you be able to assist me further. Its not working and I think its something to do with my timestaps. They seem to be different in PHP that they are in jQuery,
This is my PHP timestamp  -1434844800.
This is my .now stamp - 1434718699832.
The php stamp will always be before the JS one.

Comment: @AlexKnopp, What is the value of `<?php echo (strtotime($startdate)); ?>`? Can you post the generated HTML we will have better idea

Comment: Ive added the HTML above

Answer (score 0):

Satpals code is solving your problem except the day thing. 
You could make the comparison using the day before and use that day.
In order to do that you could create a function that finds the day before.
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) you can find all you need to know about the Date method. 
You could find the current day and then substract 1

```
var yesterday = new Date();
 d.setDate(yesterday.getDate()-1);
```

but then you should make the neccesary checks if it is the first day of the month, substract also the month, etc.

Comment: But doesnt the .getDate just return the day of the month. Dont I need to be running this against a whole timestamp since the data in my cell is a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

@all of you. 
Thanks for all your help but I found what I can see is a more efficient way to solve my issue. I've actually come away from js and used some PHP instead. It means I can actually remove the record from my loop before its displayed and thus doesn't need to be hidden.

FYI, I noticed the timestamps were different between the js versions and the php version. So I generated a new time stamp in my loop to run a condition against. This now works perfect. If the $arrival date timestamp was equal to or greater than $today timestamp, then include the HTML (), else, loop again.

Thanks for all your help anyway.